# React native scroll to top of flatlist onChangeText

Tags: react-native

I currently have a search bar component that renders a flatlist when i search for any text.

My problem is for example, i searched for football, the flatlist renders all the football posts which i can scroll down to see all. If i scroll to the middle of the flatlist then decide to search for basketball, the flatlist renders the basketball post but it does not start from the top of the list, it starts from the same position it stopped at the football search.

How do i implement when the onChangeText of search scrollToTop or any alternative solution that does the same?

Here is my code:

```
 const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

 const updateSearch=(search)=>{
 setSearch(search);
 }

 useEffect(() => {
  if(page>0)
 loadPosts(search,page);
  }, [page,search]);

 <SearchBar 
    placeholder="Search" 
    onChangeText={updateSearch} 
    value={search} 
    autoFocus = {true}
    onClear={()=>setPage(0)}
    />

  <FlatList
      data={search===""? emptyList:filteredList} />
```

Comment: Can you give me a snack url?

Comment: @J.Doe i have never used snack before, if your require more of my code please tell me and will add to question above.

Comment: You can paste your code [here](http://snack.expo.io), press save and share URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't run your snack, there are some missing parts but you can do the following:

1. declare ref variable for the FlatList

   `const ref = React.useRef();`
2. Pass it in the FlatList component

   `<FlatList ref={ref} ... />`
3. Inside **updateSearch** function, if the text is empty, you can scroll to top manually.

   ```
   const updateSearch = (search) => {
      ref.current.scrollToIndex({ index: 0 });
      setSearch(search);
   }
   ```

P.S. This just a *workaround*.

Comment: this did not work, what i want is whenever the text changes i search bar i scroll to top of flatlist. in your solution, it works only if search is empty not when any change happens to search

Comment: @kd12345 You mean that every time when you type something?

Comment: yes exactly, anytime i type something in search bar

Comment: Then remove if statement.

Comment: Call **ref.current.scrollTo({ y: 0 });** all the time when **updateSearch** is fired.

Comment: i keep getting ref.current.scrollTo is not a function

Comment: Did you declare ref variable?

Comment: yes like this const ref = React.useRef(); i have even tried importing useRef from react and using const ref =useRef() and still getting same error

Comment: when i go with the cursor on current i find get this (property) React.MutableRefObject<undefined>.current: undefined

Comment: @kd12345 I'm sorry, I updated my answer. scrollTo is for ScrollView and scrollToIndex for FlatList.

Comment: no worries, just tested scrolltoindex i keep getting invariant violation. scrolltoindex out of range. requested index 0 but maximum is -1

Comment: i used     ref.current.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 }); and it worked, do you mind explaining why? thank you,

Comment: Yes, I was going to write to try scrollToOffset. I don't know what was wrong with scrollToIndex, maybe it's related to your array. Both of them are a way to scroll to some position using index/offset. scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 }); in your case calculates distance from top (y-axis) and zero means that every time it scrolls to top.

Comment: thank you alot really appreciate it, what i am trying to accomplish there is that when i scroll my flatlist down, the search bar is hidden and the tabs and the flatlist take up the entire screen.

Comment: You mean you want to move up the search bar until it disappears?

Comment: yes that is correct but my problem is i want the tabs and the flatlist to take up the white space the search bar leaves when it moves up. I have added all the dimensions of the screen there to help out.